# Are there Muggles who got away with finding out about the magical world "unpermitted"?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

In the latest *Fantastic Beasts* trailer, the final scene shows an individual saying, "No humans can do these things you're capable of."

While as far as I can tell, the black lady is not a Muggle (probably the minister or some leader, based on her giant portrait in an earlier scene), I haven't scrutinised the scene enough to know if the others present are Muggles or not.

Nonetheless, it did get me thinking: Besides chosen government officials and parents of Muggle-borns (i.e. Muggles who are informed about the magical world on a need-to-know basis), are there any Muggles who found out about the magical world, have no need to know, and somehow gotten away with it, maybe to the extent that the magical community is unaware of such a leak for at least some time?

Comment: *"No human can do what **this thing** is capable of"* is what I heard....

Comment: Oh...That makes more sense given the movie title...nonetheless though my question still stands lol

Comment: Also, yes the "black lady" is President of MACUSA. Question still stands though... the guy Newt is sharing room with looks/acts like a Muggle...

Comment: Maybe he happens to be some Muggle companion - a host of guide - that somehow has permission to know. Or he could be the Ron Weasley of the show...

Comment: Maybe a few people slip through the cracks, but most muggles would just call them crazy.

Comment: Tom Riddle Sr. might fit your definition... he survived unscathed for 16 years...

Comment: He's definitely a Muggle who gets 'dragged along for the ride' somehow, they've confirmed in other videos that he is indeed a Muggle main character.

Comment: a muggle character brought into the wizarding world will be important as he will serve as the audience surrogate "oh - this thing? It's a wand, here's how it works..."

Comment: Wow, that should be interesting.

Answer (score 36):

### Absolutely

In 1932, a Welsh Green Dragon terrorized sunbathers on a beach near Ilfracombe. A wizard family on vacation modified the memories of the nearby Muggles, but it appears that some were not caught. From p. xxviii of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*:

> In his 1972 book *Muggles Who Notice*, Blenheim Stalk asserts that some
>   residents of Ilfracombe escaped the Mass Memory Charm. “To this day, a
>   Muggle bearing the nickname ‘Dodgy Dirk’ holds forth in bars along the
>   south coast on the subject of a ‘dirty great flying lizard’ that
>   punctured his lilo.”

Indeed, this quotes is also notable insofar as it establishes the existence of a entire book about Muggles who becomes aware of Wizarding activity, implying the existence of many more cases than just this one.

In addition, there have been numerous sightings of Yeti and the Loch Ness monster.

The Ilfracombe Incident is notable, though, because those who escaped were likely aware **not only of the existence of dragons, but of wizards, since a wizarding family immediately performed Memory Charms on most present.**

Comment: Seven! This is nice. Don't upvote more please (but give my Fawkes answer three more for 77 lol).

Comment: Nah, too bad. you answer is good enough for one more upvote.

Comment: Now you're on double seven!

Comment: Great sourced answer, but I don’t see how you make the last inference: “because those who escaped were likely aware not only of the existence of dragons, but of wizards”.  From Dodgy Dirk’s perspective, he remembers the dragon, and everyone else who was there has somehow forgotten about it or gone into denial.  But to get from that to “…so it must have been wizards that made them forget!” is a pretty big leap.

Comment: If they had stuck around long enough to actually see the wizards who arrived to perform memory charms, odds are they would've been caught in it. I imagine the ones who escaped just ran away as soon as a dragon turned up, and were never found.

Comment: Sorry, my upvote just took you off quadruple 7.

Comment: There's not enough information to know whether "escaped" means that they were aware of the memory charm and avoided it, or whether they were already gone. They _may or may not_ know about wizards in addition to dragons.